# What does this phrase mean? Wer hat Ihnen denn ins Hirn geschissen?

Tags: meaning

What does this phrase mean?

> Wer hat Ihnen denn ins Hirn geschissen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be roughly translated to English as

> Who has planted that bullshit into your brain?

or

> Who took a crap on your brain?

You should notice that this is very rude, and not appropriate for serious and professional conversation.
If someone attends to you in that way in a professional context, you should probably escalate that to a higher management level for inappropriate behavior, unless it was a response to a really silly, unconscious or absolutely unacceptable statement made from your side.

Comment: The use of the "polite" pronoun "Ihnen" makes it even more offensive.